# Python: Van Der Pol equation

Tags: python, numpy, plot, parameters, scipy

Currently, i am trying to understand how to use [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

The equation to solve is the Van Der Pol equation

[image]

So the initial variables are the following

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t0tf = np.array([0, 6.663286859323130189])  # [t0, tf]
x = np.array([2.008619860874843136, 0])     # [x1, x2]
N = 25                                      # Number of sub intervals
T = np.linspace(t0tf[0], t0tf[1], N+1)      # array with all the times
```

After that, i defined the following functions

```
def vdp(t, x):
    ''' Vander Pol equation
    :param t: time
    :type t: int/float
    :param x: state vector, [x1, x2]
    :type x: np.array
    :xpoint: derivative vector
    '''
    x1, x2 = x
    return np.array([x2, (1 - x1 ** 2) * x2 - x1])

def run_vanderpol(fun, x, t):
   ''' To call the scipy.integrate.odeint '''
   y = scipy.integrate.odeint(fun, x, t)
   return y, t

and i call:
x0 = np.array([2.008619860874843136, 0])
N = 25
t = np.linspace(0, 6.663286859323130189, N+1)
print(run_vanderpol(vdp, x0, t))
```

And doing so always causes an error. So by doing so some research, i figured out that by defining `vdp` like this...

```
def vdp(x, t):       # Switched the t and x from before
    ''' Vander Pol equation
    :param t: time
    :type t: int/float
    :param x: state vector, [x1, x2]
    :type x: np.array
    :xpoint: derivative vector
    '''
    x1, x2 = x
    return np.array([x2, (1 - x1 ** 2) * x2 - x1])
```

... the call of `scipy.integrate.odeint` works and returns the correct results (i think).

The problem now, we were asked to define `vdp` as a function that takes `t` and `x` (in that specific order i think). And i cannot figure out how to make the `scipy.integrate.odeint` call work by defining `vdp` with `t` as the first param, and then `x`..

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: there is an argument called `tfirst` according to the document: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: For this function argument tfirst exists, as mentioned above. For any cases when it's not implemented you can do the simple trick like the following: run_vanderpol(lambda x,t : vdp(t,x), x0, t)